# Monitor disk space in an `until` loop

Tags: bash

my first question here. Hope it's a good one.

So I'm hoping to create a script that kills another script running `arecord` when my disk gets to a certain usage. (I should point out, I'm not exactly sure how I got to that `df` filter... just kinda searched around...) My plan is to run both scripts (the one recording, and the one monitoring disk usage) in separate `screen`s.

I'm doing this all on a Raspberry Pi, btw.

So this is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISK=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')

until [ $DISK -ge 50 ]
    do
        sleep 1
    done

killall arecord
```

This code works when I play with the starting value ("50" changed to "30" or so). But it doesn't seem to "monitor" my disk the way I want it to. I have a bit of an idea what's going on: the variable DISK is only assigned once, not checked or redefined periodically.

In other words, I probably want something *in* my `until` loop that "gets" the disk usage from `df`, right? What are some good ways of going about it?

=

PS I'd be super interested in hearing how I might incorporate this whole script's purpose into the script running arecord itself, but that's beyond me right now... and another question...

Comment: Just move the assignment into the loop. And add quotes arround `$DISK` so that it doesn't fail the first round.

Comment: Thanks! // I was taking a nap earlier and realized how silly I'd been. I am very new to programing.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* only setting `DISK` once since it's done before the loop starts and not done as part of the looping process.

A simple fix is to incorporate the evaluation of the disk space into the actual `while` loop itself, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
until [ $(df / | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}' | tr -d '%') -ge 50 ] ; do
    sleep 1
done
killall arecord
```

You'll notice I've made some minor mods to the command as well, specifically:

- You can use `awk` itself to get the relevant line from the `ps` output, no need to use `grep` in a separate pipeline stage.
- I prefer `tr` for deleting single characters, `sed` can do it but it's a bit of overkill.